# How to paste one occurrence of filtered category to a new column in EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with several rows for each category(column) and a corresponding score for them in excel. I want to get the sum of all scores for each category(I will use the `SUMIF` formula). I want to know how to extract one occurrence of each category name onto a separate column without manually typing it. Is there a formula or a shortcut that I could use?

[image: Screen shot of filter]

Comment: Please show your source data as text which can be copy/pasted. Take a look at this [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables). It is then much easier to help you. Also it would help to help you if you show us the expected result as well. Reading [repro] will help you to improve your question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved by using the `UNIQUE` function. Suppose you have the following data as an example in the range `A1:B8`:

[image: data]

Now simply copy your headings into, e.g., the columns `D:E` and enter the following formulas in the cells `D2` and `E2` respectively:

```
=UNIQUE(A2:A8)
=SUMIF($A$2:A8;D2;$B$2:$B$8)
```

Adjust the arrays to your needs and you should have solved your problem. The final output looks as follows:

[image: output]